# jquery tablesorter scroller height

Tags: javascript, height, tablesorter, scroller

I am trying to set a dynamic height to tablesorter scroll.

The general idea is the following: my table will be browsed with different devices, laptop, mobiles and tablets; I can set the initial value of the scroller (I.e. scroller_height : 500 ) but I would like to set this value dynamically according to the screen resolution and the screen orientation. 
I mean: if I browse the table from my laptop (1366 x 768) I would like to have the scroller_height : 500, if browse my table with the desktop monitor (1920 x 1080) I would like to have a scroller_height : 600. 
Moreover I could browse that table with my tablet both in landscape or in portrait mode; in case of orientation change the table width is automatically adjusted to fit the "changed" width: I would like to have the same behavior for the height. 
I.E. laptop res 1280 x 800 : if I browse the table in landscape I would like to have the scroller_height : 500, if I rotate the device I would like to adjust the height to (for example) scroller_height : 800.
In general I would like to:

- retrieve dynamically the screen dimension
- adjust the scroller height (and so the table height) according to the screen dimension retrieved
- catch the orientation change event
- modify the scroller height (and so the table height) according to the new orientation.

In theory I have all clear. Practically I have no idea.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version, if you set the [`scroller_height` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-scroller.html#scroller-height) to zero or an empty string, the scroller will be set to full height. Then all you would need to do is add a css media query to set the desired `max-height`.